# Understanding input pins

Tags: arduino, switches, input, voltmeter

I am trying to gain a better understanding of input pins. As per my current understanding, they act as a voltmeter with super high resistance and are connected to the ground on one side. When connected to another point in the circuit, they measure the voltage relative to the ground.

I am looking at a schematic of a basic input switch:

[image]

Is it correct to schematically describe the circuit with this diagram?

[image]

Looking at the second diagram, I am unable to understand how the voltage will be set to 5 when the switch is opened, as there is a voltage drop on resistor R1. Additionally, I have seen many switch diagrams without the R2 resistor, which they claim is essential to avoid a short-circuit. For reference, I am using the Freenova starter kit and tutorial (the schematic is from there).

Comment: What causes the volt drop on R1?

Comment: As to my knowledge, every resistor the current passes through causes a voltage drop. maybe I'm confusing things?

Comment: @TomerGigi You are absolutely correct. There is a voltage drop based on current flow. Also can be said in other words, no voltage drop if no current flows. We cannot understand why you assume there is a voltage drop, what current would flow to cause it?

Comment: Why do you assume a current is flowing?

Answer (score 2):

> Looking at the second diagram, I am unable to understand how the voltage will be set to 5 when the switch is opened, as there is a voltage drop on resistor R1.

No, what is unclear from the diagram is that the input resistance of the pin is much, much higher than 10 kΩ so very little current flows in and the voltage drop across R1 and R2 is negligible when the switch is open. 'V' will read 5 V.

> I have seen many switch diagrams without the R2 resistor, which they claim is essential to avoid a short-circuit.

The situation they are protecting against is as follows:

- GPIO has been configured in software as an output.
- GPIO has been set high (so it's trying to maintain 5 V at the output).
- The button gets pressed. Without R2 that applies a short-circuit to ground to the GPIO output. This may damage the device. With R2 in circuit the current is limited to \$ I = \frac V R = \frac 5 {10k} = 0.5\ \text {mA}\$. (Most of the microcontrollers can output 20 mA or so without difficulty - but may be limited to the total current on all pins as it all has to pass through one of the supply pins).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could model the circuit like that. It is essentially same thing as connecting it to a multimeter instead of input, you can be sure that the voltages are as expected.

And no, when button is pushed, there is no current flowing anywhere and thus no voltage drops anywhere, as like you said, the input is a super high impedance, you can assume it is infinitely high so there is no impedance at all so it looks like an open circuit.

And the R2 is not related to the pin being an input, but protects the pin from damage if someone accidentally sets it as an output.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the circled "V" symbol is a voltmeter, measuring potential difference. Voltmeters have extremely high (ideally infinite) resistance, and so your circuit can be redrawn without it, and without changing the behaviour at all:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOixLe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There is clearly no current able to flow through R2, because there's nowhere for it to go; node A is not connected to anything that could draw current via that route:

$$ I_3 = 0 $$

Same story for \$I_2\$; since the switch is open, there's no way current can flow via that route either:

$$ I_2 = 0 $$

[Kirchoff's current law](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-6/kirchhoffs-current-law-kcl/) (KCL) tells us that current \$I\$, through R1, must be the sum of those two currents:

$$ I = I_2 + I_3 = 0 $$

In other words, no current is flowing through R1.

Ohm's law then tells us what voltage \$V_{R1}\$ we can expect to find across R1:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{R1} &= I \times R_1 \\ \\
&= 0A \times 10k\Omega \\ \\
&= 0V
\end{aligned}
$$

If there is no potential *difference* across R1, then there is no difference between the potential at the top of R1 (+5V) and the potential \$V_B\$ at the bottom:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_B &= +5V - V_{R1} \\ \\
&= +5V - 0V \\ \\
&= +5V
\end{aligned}
$$

Your mistake was to assume there would be a significant voltage "drop" across R1. There is not, because there is no current flowing through it. As long as SW1 is open, there would still be no current flowing even with a voltmeter in place (between A and ground), because voltmeters (ideally) have infinite resistance.

The same argument can be made to predict the potential \$V_A\$ at node A. Use Ohm's law to calculate the potential difference across R2:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{R2} &= I_3 \times R_2 \\ \\
&= 0A \times 10k\Omega \\ \\
&= 0V
\end{aligned}
$$

Again, with no potential difference across R2, the potential \$V_B\$ at node B must be the same as \$V_A\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_A &= V_B - V_{R2} \\ \\
&= V_B - 0V \\ \\
&= +5V - 0V \\ \\
&= +5V
\end{aligned}
$$

The input pin of a microcontroller has very, very high resistance. It's as if it's not even there. It draws no current, just like a good voltmeter wouldn't, and so all the above reasoning remains valid even if you connect node A to a microcontroller input.

As an exercise, I encourage you to try and apply Ohm's and Kirchhoff's laws to the system when the switch is *closed*, to understand in a much more rigourous way why the potential at A (and B) falls to 0V. In that scenario, you may consider the switch to be a resistor with very low resistance, close to 0Ω.

Comment: W.r.t. ``The input pin of a microcontroller has very, very high resistance``, some microcontroller pins have ESD diode clamps to the ground and VCC rails. The diode clamps may conduct if (a) the input voltage is present when the microcontroller isn't powered (b) the input voltage is negative or above VCC. Not sure if worth mentioning that in the answer.

Comment: @ChesterGillon I think it would be out of scope for the question. If this was included, then where to draw the line what other things should be included. The list is long, including internal pull resistors, leakage currents and input capacitance, which are also not needed assuming normal use of IO pin for reading a pushbutton with 10k pull-up to MCU supply.

Answer (score 0):

R2 is not really needed in a final product. It might be a good idea to have it on evaluation boards, as the user might incorrectly configure the pin to output. The outcome would not be terrible, modern hardware survives shorted pins, but still it's better to avoid. The production firmware always configures the pin correctly.

Anyway R2 has no effect on the operation. The input pin has huge impedance so the voltage drop on R2 (and R1) due to input current is negligible. You get either 5V through R1+R2 or 0V through R2 only, with no voltage drop on the resistors.

In fact R1 can be eliminated too, as most modern microcontrollers feature programmable pull resistors on all pins. You can enable an internal pull-up resistor on the pin and connect the switch directly without any external resistors.

And here comes the last caveat. The internal pull resistors (and bus keepers) are usually in the range of 25k-100k. A 10k external resistor might possibly be insufficient to set a proper logic level if the internal resistors are also activated. If you use the internal pull-up, and still want to have R2 to limit the current in case of bad pin configuration, use 4.7k or less.